# How to return a promise from a Cypress custom command in typescript?

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am converting an existing custom command to typescript and have hit a snag.  My custom command returns a `Promise`, which Cypress automatically handles and converts to a `Cypress.Chainable`, but typescript doesn't know about this magic so it throws an error.  Is this possible?  Any advice?

```
function test(): Cypress.Chainable<string> {
  return new Cypress.Promise<string>(resolve => {
    resolve("some data");
  });
}

Cypress.Commands.add("test", test);
```

Gives me:

```
[ts] Type 'Bluebird<string>' is missing the following properties from type 'Chainable<string>': and, as, blur, check, and 75 more.
```

I have handled this with other commands by `cy.wrap()`ing the return value to convert it to a `Cypress.Chainable`, but I can't figure out how to do this properly with a `Promise`:

```
function test(): Cypress.Chainable<string> {
  return new Cypress.Promise<string>(resolve => {
    resolve("some data");
  }).then(data => {
    return cy.wrap(data);
  });
}
```

Gives me:

```
[ts] Type 'Bluebird<Chainable<string>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Chainable<string>': and, as, blur, check, and 75 more.
```

Or if I switch it around:

```
function test(): Cypress.Chainable<string> {
  return cy.wrap(
    new Cypress.Promise<string>(resolve => {
      resolve("some data");
    })
  );
}
```

Gives me:

```
[ts]
Type 'Chainable<Bluebird<string>>' is not assignable to type 'Chainable<string>'.  Type 'Bluebird<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky solution that I am using now and am sharing it here in case it helps anyone.  I refactored the promise to execute a callback instead and am waiting for the value set by that callback to be defined.  I'm not going to accept this answer because there has to be a better way closer to the original question.

```
function getData(successFn: (data: string) => void) {
  // do some work to get the data here
  successFn("some data");
}

function test(): Cypress.Chainable<string> {
  const start = Date.now();
  let toReturn: string | undefined;
  getData(data => { toReturn = data; }

  while (Date.now() < start + 5000) {
    if (toReturn) {
      return cy.wrap(toReturn);
    }
  }

  throw new Error("timed out waiting for data")
}

Cypress.Commands.add("test", test);
```